# Create a dog class and tester

Tags: java, class

Hello I was asked to create the following:
Create a Dog class that keeps track of a dog's

1. name
2. age
3. Weight

Have the following methods available to use:

```
1. getName(): String
2. setName(String): void
3. getAge():int
4. getDogYears():int (assume 1 human year = 5 dog years)
5. addAYear():void
6. setAge(int):void
7. getWeight(): double
8. setWeight(double): void
9. getDogData():String
```

Create a DogTester class to test each of the methods above

I am following a template of this done before but I am getting confused, this is what I have so far
Dog class:

```
public class Dog
{
    //Instance vars
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double weight;

    //constructor
    public Dog(String initName)
    {
        name = initName;
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
    }

    //methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public int getDogYears()
    {
        return age*5;
    }

    public void addAYear()
    {
        age = age + 1;
    }

    public void setAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight()
    {
        weight = weight;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        String data = "";
        data = name;
        data = data + "\n\tAge: " + age;
        data = data + "\n\tWeight: " + weight;


        return data;
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

        //Create two dogs to keep track of
        Dog s1 = new Dog("Balto");

        //get the dogs age
        System.out.print("Enter the dog's age: "); //prompt
        double grade = in.nextDouble();             //read
        s1.addAge( years );                     //store

        //get the dogs weight
        System.out.print("Enter the dog's weight: "); //prompt
        s1.addWeight( in.nextDouble() );                //read AND store

        //output their data
        System.out.println( s1.getData() );

    }
}
```

I am confused as what it would want from the public void constructors and also as to how to set up a tester for these

Comment: Well the first problem to tackle would be using methods in your tester that do not exist in your object (e.g. addAge(double years)). That is certainly not going to compile, nor "test" the object.

Comment: I don't think your test class should be interacting with the user, other than to report whether the tests succeeded.  It should simply create some `Dog`s, call some methods, and check some results.

Comment: Also, have another look at `setName`, `setAge` and `setWeight`.  Your versions don't seem right to me.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor is not "void", nor does it really "return" anything. When you do:

```
new Dog("Balto");
```

This allocates space for a `Dog` object and calls the constructor to initialize it.

To test the constructor, all you really need to do is test to make sure that the constructor is behaving as it should. Define some clear rules for the state the constructor needs to leave a `Dog` in (these are commonly called "postconditions"). In your case, looking at the code, it seems that for a new `Dog`:

- The name must be set to the parameter passed to the constructor.
- The age and weight are initialized to 0.

So all you need to do then is, after constructing a new `Dog`, verify that those conditions are true. Get the dogs name, see if it is the expected value. Get the age and weight, make sure they are zero. If so, then your constructor stuck to the "contract" you defined, and your test passed.

Answer (score 1):

Your public statement simply states that those methods can be accessed from outside the class. If on the other hand you did not want anyone to change a dog's weight after initially constructing the dog, you would set it to private.

You only have one constructor here, the other statements are methods to change your instance variables:

```
public Dog(String initName)
{
    name = initName;
    age = 0;
    weight = 0;
}
```

To test you would need to create a dog and then run some assert statements against it to verify that your methods are doing what you would expect them to:

```
Dog d = new Dog("Pooch");
assertEquals("The name is incorrect", "Pooch", d.getName());
```

Comment: You would also want to mention explicitly that you are using here a test framework like JUnit or TestNG

Comment: Good call.... I should mention I was assuming you are using a JUnit test class for your testing. If you are not familiar with JUnit, I would do a little research and download the appropriate plug-in for your IDE. Test Driven Development is the way to go so ideally you would create these test cases first and then build your dog class afterward.